# how do I prevent anchor tag from redirecting in javascript when a validation fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have HTML with 5 tabs with form fields and button at the bottoms to navigate to next tab. I want to prevent tab switching if validation fails on the click of Next button. Presently when validation fails tab switches to next tab. I have tried both `event.preventDefault()` and `return false` individually and combined but none of these worked in chrome browser. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active" id="libdet">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#bdetails">1. Service Basic details</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#soptions">2. Service Options</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#addInfor">3. Service Add. info</a>
        </li>    
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#addImgs">4. Images</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tandc">5. Terms &amp; Conditions</a
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#soptions">
        <button name="next" id="nextSB" onclick="validatefirsttab()">NEXT</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

```js
function validatefirsttab() {
    if (document.form.productTitle.value == "") {
        alert("Please provide Service title!");
        document.form.productTitle.focus();
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `onclick="return validatefirsttab(event)"`

Comment: Please take the time to format your code correctly. It makes it much easier to read and means you'll be more likely to get a quick and accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks Rory, sure I will.

Answer (score 1):

You can use click function directly in jQuery. Your button have an ID that you can use, so:

```
$("#nextSB").click(function(e){
    if (document.form.productTitle.value == "") {
        alert("Please provide Service title!");
        document.form.productTitle.focus();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then your button will be:

```
<button name="next" id="nextSB">NEXT</button>
```

In my opinion, this solution is cleaner than use `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @erikscandola

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Guys! I found an answer.

Here is the modified code:

- Added event as parameter on function.
- And 1 more call to `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`

Javascript:

```
function validatefirsttab(event)
      {

         if( document.form.productTitle.value == "" )
         {
            alert( "Please provide Service title!" );
            document.form.productTitle.focus() ;
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation(); // Added now
         }
       }
```

HTML:

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#soptions">
  <button name="next" id="nextSB" onclick="return validatefirsttab(event);" >NEXT
  </button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bootstrap.js? It is likely that another jQuery listener is triggering the tabs to change.

If this is the case, you'd want to remove the `<a data-toggle="tab" href="#soptions">` (which is triggering the tab switch) and create a new jQuery listener for your 'Next' button. You'd place your `validatefirsttab()` function inside of the bootstrap tab function:

```
<div class="row">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active" id="libdet">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#bdetails">1. Service Basic details</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#soptions">2. Service Options</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#addInfor">3. Service Add. info</a>
    </li>    
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#addImgs">4. Images</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tandc">5. Terms &amp; Conditions</a
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <button name="next" id="nextSB">NEXT</button>
</div>

<script>
    $('#nextSB').on('click',function() {
        if (document.form.productTitle.value == "") {
            alert("Please provide Service title!");
        } else {
            $('a[href="#soptions"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
        }
    })
</script>
```

Not tested, and again I'm assuming you're using [bootstrap.js togglable tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

Hash tag links (`href="#foo"`) won't trigger a page refresh, so `e.preventDefault` and the like aren't useful here. It is common practice to use hash tag links with jQuery or javascript for precisely that reason.